# Using SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder to change color in a listView. android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-viewbinder

I was trying to change color on a text in a ListView, so I created ViewBinder but my text is still white, nothing change, what can I do with it?

```
// map each name to a TextView
    String[] from = new String[] { "event" };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.countryTextView };
    conAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Clock.this, R.layout.day_plan, null, from, to);
    setListAdapter(conAdapter); // set adapter

    SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder binder = new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex){    
            int getIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("colour");
            String color = cursor.getString(getIndex);
           tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.countryTextView);

            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

           if(color.equals("Green"))
            {                   
                tv.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0,255,0));
                return true;
            } 
            return false;          
        }};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you call `conAdapter.setViewBinder(SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder)`? That is, are you sure those methods are actually being called?

Also change one of those lines:

```
       tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.countryTextView); // <-- add 'view.'
```

Comment: how and where should I call it?

Comment: Add `conAdapter.setViewBinder(binder);` right after your code. Try putting in a `Log.d()` to verify that `setTextColor()` is actually being called.

Comment: Im getting error : 

01-11 21:15:07.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1144): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-11 21:15:07.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1144): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: At what line of code is this occurring? It sounds like the `Cursor` you got is not valid; what line of code returns this `Cursor` that you're trying to set on the adapter?

Comment: now it's working, but its displaying invisible text, or not text at all. but it displays rows because of the line which is separating items from listview

Comment: Can you post your day_plan.xml?

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/countryTextView" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:padding="8dp"
   android:textSize="20sp" 
   android:textColor="@android:color/white"
   android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
   android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
`

Comment: its working ok, when i comment this section with ViewBinder, I mean it displays all of the entries, but changing font-color is really important for me

Comment: I deleted the font color information from XMl, and then change text color and it worked, but only the first one, I mean when color equals something and it goes into this if condition it displays transparent font, do You have any idea why ?

Comment: it worked but, it changes font color in all rows, how can i change it only in one?

Comment: You would need some sort of `if` condition within your `ViewBinder` which would exclusively set the color if it is met... no idea on the transparent font though. Did you get it working though?

Comment: yes, I manage to transform the code, but its still change color for all list not only for one entry.

Comment: Oops, can't believe I didn't notice that; see my updated answer.